# The product vs lex. order topology on $\mathbb Z ^\omega$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_\Pi$ and $\tau _<$ be the product and lexicographic order topologies on $\mathbb Z ^\omega$.

I believe $(\mathbb Z^\omega,\tau_\Pi)$ and $(\mathbb Z^\omega,\tau_<)$ are both homeomorphic (to the irrationals, in fact).

My question is, are the two topologies actually equal as sets.  Does $\tau_\Pi=\tau _<$?

Comment: What is your reference wrt the order topology? I. e. that the resulting space is homeomorphic to the irrationals. The product case is classical. But it seems to me that product basic sets need not be order-open.

Comment: maybe I am wrong. What is a product basic set that is not order-open?

Comment: To consider: what points are in the open (lexicographic) interval between $l=(0,0,0,0,1,\ldots)$ and $u=(0,0,0,0,-1,0,\ldots)$ ? Can you generalise?